# Call parent shortcode from nested shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Is it possible from nested shortcode to call its parent shortcode?

To illustrate my idea take into account this example:

```
[check-auth]
    [has-auth]Hello, dear Username[/has-auth]
    [no-auth]Please login here[/no-auth]
[/check-auth]
```

The idea is to check authorization in parent shortcode `check-auth` and then to use this information inside nested shortcodes `has-auth` and `no-auth`.

I do also understand that if this would be possible it means that we are binding together these shortcodes so that you cannot use `has-auth` outside `check-auth` (actually you can write `has-auth` so that is will handle this case too), and that this is not a good design desicion but still it would allow to write complex shortcodes with logic :)

Comment: The only way to do so that I see right now is to manually query nested shortcode inside `$content` and then to call `do_shortcode($parsedShortcode)`.

Comment: Or to use global php variables which is a bad practice but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is to use class for a shortcode that has nested shortcodes. So that from the nested shortcode you can always get access to some `$this->property` or call an `$this->instanceMethod()`.

Basic example of a shortcode defined in class you can find here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode#Examples.

Comment: Addressed example uses class with static method (thus no variables). would you please explain your idea more?